# Display pdf file in svelte application using pdfjs library from mozilla

Tags: svelte, pdf.js

I have a Showpdf.svelte component as shown in the code below. If this code is called in the component's App.svelte and is executed, the pdf file does not show in the browser, instead downloads. I want to display a pdf file in the browser using the sveltejs application. I am very grateful if anyone helps with this problem.

```
<script>
    pdfjsLib
        .getDocument("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf")
        .then((doc) => {
            console.log(doc._pdfInfo.numPages);
            doc.getPages(1).then((page) => {
                let myCanvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
                let context = myCanvas.getContetxt("2d");

                let viewport = page.getViewport(1);
                myCanvas.width = viewport.width;
                myCanvas.height = viewport.height;

                page.render({
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport,
                });
            });
        });
</script>

<style>
</style>

<canvas id="my_canvas" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to your canvas with the [`bind:this` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element) and use that to render the PDF in [as outlined by the Examples section](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/#hello-world-using-base64-encoded-pdf) of the documentation.

**Example**

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    let canvasRef;
    
    const data = atob(
        'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
        'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
        'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
        'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
        'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
        'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
        'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
        'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
        'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
        'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
        'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
        'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
        'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G'
    );
    
    // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
    const pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
    
    // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
    
    pdfjsLib
        .getDocument({ data }).promise
        .then(doc => doc.getPage(1))
        .then(page => {
            const scale = 1.5;
            const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });

            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
            var context = canvasRef.getContext('2d');
            canvasRef.height = viewport.height;
            canvasRef.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            };

            page.render(renderContext);
        });
</script>

<canvas bind:this={canvasRef} />
```

Comment: Does this open pdf in editable format too(you know the one created using acrobat with editable textfields and checkbox)? If not, can you tell which library can do that?